# Error at Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this fact at PROLOG (swi)

```
pos(X,[K|T],Z) :- findall(X, (member(X, [K|T])), Z) .
```

and then I write this:

```
pos (5 , [1,4,5] , Z ).
```

and I get the following error.

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: pos 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: (5 , [1,4,5] , Z ) .
```

I am new to prolog so I cannot understand what the interpreter tells me about and secondly what I am doing wrong

Thx in advance.

Comment: You aren't typing the question mark in front of `?pos` are you? Also, no spaces allowed between `pos` and `(5 , [1,4,5] , Z ).` You should enter `pos( 5 , [1,4,5] , Z ).`

Comment: @mbratch yes the '?' is written by mistake. So to sum up spaces do count in prolog?

Comment: A space is a problem if it separates a predicate name and the opening parenthesis of the parameter list. Prolog determines that a predicate has parameters when the open parenthesis is "attached" to the predicate name. This is true in a variety of programming languages (although not all). You can, however, have spaces between the arguments and the commas and the parentheses, as this example shows.

Comment: @mbratch ok I got it! Thx a lot for your time